# Nominations End Soon

Tags: support, election

It would be great to get a 4th candidate for our Moderator Election. Then the folks at SE will feel like this is a successful election. Is anyone else interested in joining the team of moderators for this site?

[I personally think it's plenty good enough to have 3 nominees for the 3 positions. But if we had a 4th nominee, then we'd know who we could turn to if one person needed to drop off for personal reasons at some point.]

Comment: If you look at the nominations from the last election there were two others last time; maybe one of them would be interested if they got a ping.